# preventing redundant random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, loops, random, redundancy

I'm trying to get random numbers 0 - 499 in sets of 2 based on what the user inputs. For example 234 and 58, and thats one set, but the user may prompt that they wan 8 sets. Im trying to make sure that a redundant number doesnt show up, like 234 & 58, 12 & 444, 198 & 58. (58 showed up twice.)

The way im trying to prevent this is by putting the found numbers into an array and when i go around the next match im checking in the array to make sure they havent been used yet. Was just wondering what the best way of this would be. Like obviously on the first go around no numbers have been chosen yet so i dont need to check. but then the next go around what if i get a redundant? i will get numbers and then check the array, and if it is already in the array how do i go back and get new numbers? a do while loop maybe?

here is what im doing:

```
//now add the specified number of random connections
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("new connection(s): ");

    //array for keeping track of the new connections to prevent redundant add's
    int redundant [] = new int[con*2];

    for( int i = 1; i <= con; i++ ){
        Random ran = new Random();
        if( i == 1){
            int ran1 = ran.nextInt(sWorld.length-1) + 1;
            int ran2 = ran.nextInt(sWorld.length-1) + 1;
            redundant[i - 1] = ran1;
            redundant[i] = ran2;
            System.out.println("     " + ran1 + " - " + ran2);
        }
        else{
            int ran1 = ran.nextInt(sWorld.length-1) + 1;
            int ran2 = ran.nextInt(sWorld.length-1) + 1;
            //need help
        }
```

thanks in advance!

**EDIT. Going with a maethod below (using collections)**

```
        List<Integer> nums = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    for( int i = 0; i <= 499; i++ ){ 
        nums.add(i);
    }

    //shuffle the collection for more randomness


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("new connection(s): ");
    for (int x = 1; x <= con; x++){
        Collections.shuffle(nums);

        Random ran = new Random();
        int r1 = nums.remove(ran.nextInt(nums));
        int r2 = nums.remove(ran.nextInt(nums));
```

but having trouble getting the random numbers, any help?

Comment: Randomly generate one number, x, then output x, x+1, x+2, ..., x+n % 500. Still perfectly random!

Comment: No, it is random, but it is not perfectly random, because you have a pattern based on the modulo classes of 500. The pattern is not random at all. You cannot generate any possible scenario using this pattern which doesn't correspond to your pattern (obviously). Also, your description is incorrect too, as x might be 499 and x+1 will be 500, it would have been to have (x+1) % 500, but the pattern is still not random.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create a list of number from 0-499

```
List<Integer> nums = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<=499; i++) nums.add(i);
```

Then shuffle the the list

```
Collections.shuffle(nums);
```

Then each time you need a non-recurring random number between 0-499, just remove an element from the list

```
int x = nums.remove()
```

Comment: thanks im actually gonna try your method, but having trouble getting a random number out. this is what im doin and it wont work (see edited part)

Comment: just added .size() after nums so now i have int r1 = nums.remove(ran.nextInt(nums.size())); because im using Random ran = new Random(); it seems to work so thanks!

Comment: Once you've done `Collections.shuffle(nums);` the list are shuffled, so even if you're always removing the first one, you'll get a random number

Answer (score 3):

Just fill a collection with all indices in the desired range (i.e. 0 to 499), and then use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).

Answer (score 0):

Use a `while` cycle and use an `array`. While your index is not out of scope generate two numbers. Add them to the array if they are not redundant and increase your index accordingly. If they are redundant, do nothing, the next iteration of the while cycle will generate two new numbers anyway.

Comment: Yeaaa im thinking this is what im looking for let me try it real quick! I just couldnt visualize it :p